# Django: Restrict instances of a class

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Position class in my model that consists of different positions that exist in an organization: director, assistant, secretary, etc. Each position is associated with a number indicating the amount of positions that may be of that type. Director can only be one, there only can de three assistants, five secretaries...

How could I restrict the model so that only they can have X people per charge?
Now I only show the number:

```
class Position(models.Model):
    cod_position = models.CharField(max_length = 9, unique=True, blank=True)
    number_position = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, blank = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `clean` method of your model: Check to see if the number of Positions has been reached and raise a ValidationError if it has been reached. For more info check the documentation for `clean` here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

Comment: And, how I could know if a position has been occupied? I mean, if there's an instance of that type. if cod_position == 'Director' and ??

Comment: Could you provide your models ?